# Selecting the most recent record for each product

Tags: sql, mysql, time-limit-exceeded

I have the following structure of a table:

```
|  id  |  profile_id  |  sku  |  vendor  | price |  importRun  |
|  1   |     39       |  123  |  myVen   |  2.0  |      1      |
|  2   |     39       |  456  |  myVen   |  2.0  |      1      |
|  3   |     39       |  123  |  myVen   |  3.0  |      2      |
```

Related: [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649696/mysql-select-distinct-while-ignoring-one-column)

(I'm not sure If I'm supposed to nearly copy/paste the question. If so, drop me a note pls and I'll update the question).

**What I want (short summary)**

Get a List of all articles in my DB. If `sku`'s are redundant, I just want the newest entry (or the highest importRun associated). I already got that going thanks to SO, but the query takes **way** too much time to execute (waiting for like 10 mins already, still no output).

This is the query I'm using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM import_data t1
INNER JOIN import_profiles imp
ON t1.profile_id = imp.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sku, MAX(importRun) AS importRun
    FROM import_data
    GROUP BY sku
) t2
ON t1.sku = t2.sku 
WHERE imp.creditornr = 73329
AND t1.vendor = 'fortinet'
AND t1.importRun = t2.importRun
```

The has ~ 50.000 entries and is expanding on a weekly base, so I assume, every week the query will take longer to execute.

Any idea on how to improve that?

Here is the `explain`

[image]

Comment: Please post either the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT`, or include the schema for the relevant tables, including indexes.

Comment: @200_success I added the explain-output.

Comment: Is changing the table schema an option? If so, make sure you store a direct reference in `import_profiles` to the most recent data set. Oh, and check your tables indexes. The explain output shows that no usable key was found on `import_data`, neither for the inner nor the outer query.